# Swift: Call Function when NSTextField is Edited

Tags: swift, macos, nstextfield

I try to dynamically update the text of another view with the changing user input of an `NSTextField`. The following approach does not work since it is for `iOS`. Is there something similar for `osx` `NSTextField` available?

```
self.equationTextField.addTarget(self, action: #selector(ViewController.textFieldDidChange(_:)), for: UIControlEvents.editingChanged)
//build error: "Use of unresolved identifier 'UIControlEvents'"
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You will have to make use of NSControlTextEditingDelegate. Connect the NSTextField `delegate` to your ViewController if you are using storyboard. If you create it programmatically can just set it in code like this: `textfield.delegate = self` in `viewDidLoad()`

In the `NSControlTextEditingDelegate` there is a `controlTextDidChange` that you can make use of to get notification when text is edited.

```
extension ViewController: NSControlTextEditingDelegate {
    override func controlTextDidChange(_ notification: Notification) {
        if let textField = notification.object as? NSTextField {
            print(textField.stringValue)
            //do what you need here
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you very much. I already found the snipped `func controlTextDidChange(_ notification: Notification)` in the swift reference but I never would have find the complete solution with using the class `extension` thing. Kind of complicated. Thanks anyway.

Comment: controlTextDidChange gives you live updates while you're typing; controlTextDidEndEditing only fires when you hit return or move to a different control.

Answer (score 2):

- I found Swift 4 issue with
- textfield.delegate = self
- AND
- NSControlTextEditingDelegate
- controlTextDidChange and controlTextDidEndEditing are in
  NSControlTextEditingDelegate
- this is a parent protocol of
  NSTextFieldDelegate protocol NSTextFieldDelegate :
  NSControlTextEditingDelegate
- so VC should implement NSTextFieldDelegate not NSControlTextEditingDelegate

---

```
class  MyViewController:.... NSControlTextEditingDelegate 
textfield.delegate = self
//compile error: Cannot assign value of type 'MyViewController' to type 'NSTextFieldDelegate?'

//
class  MyViewController:.... NSTextFieldDelegate 
textfield.delegate = self  //compiles ok
```

---

### Full example

```
//
//  MyViewController.swift
//

import Cocoa

class MyViewController: NSViewController, NSTextFieldDelegate {

    //--------------------------------------------------------------
    // MARK: -   //call in viewDidLoad
    // MARK: -
    //--------------------------------------------------------------
    func connectTONSControlTextEditingDelegate(){

        //controlTextDidChange and controlTextDidEndEditing are in NSControlTextEditingDelegate
        //this is a parent protocol of NSTextFieldDelegate
        //protocol NSTextFieldDelegate : NSControlTextEditingDelegate
        //so  implement NSTextFieldDelegate 
        //class MyViewController:.... NSTextFieldDelegate
        //then connect it here to NSTextFields

        //then override controlTextDidChange OR controlTextDidEndEditing

        self.textField0.delegate = self
        self.textField1.delegate = self

    }


    //--------------------------------------------------------------
    // MARK: -  NSControlTextEditingDelegate
    // MARK: -
    //--------------------------------------------------------------
    //called everytime you type in field
    override func controlTextDidChange(_ notification: Notification) {

        if let textField = notification.object as? NSTextField {
            if textField === textField0{
                logger.info("[controlTextDidChange][textField0]:'\(textField.stringValue)'")

            }
            else if textField === textField1{
                logger.info("[controlTextDidChange][textField1]:'\(textField.stringValue)'")

            }
            else{
                logger.error("[controlTextDidChange][UNHANDLED NSTextField]")
            }
        }
    }

    //User tapped in NSTextfields and then clicked out - text may not have changed
    //this is actually on NSObject in appkit
    //dont need both controlTextDidChange and controlTextDidEndEditing but no harm if you do
    override func controlTextDidEndEditing(_ notification: Notification){
        if let textField = notification.object as? NSTextField {

            if textField === textField0{
                logger.info("[controlTextDidEndEditing][textField0]:'\(textField.stringValue)'")

            }
            else if textField === textField1{
                logger.info("[controlTextDidEndEditing][textField1]:'\(textField.stringValue)'")

            }
            else{
                logger.error("[controlTextDidEndEditing][UNHANDLED NSTextField]")
            }
        }
    }



    //--------------------------------------------------------------
    // MARK: - NSTextFields
    // MARK: -
    //--------------------------------------------------------------
    @IBOutlet weak var textField0: NSTextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var textField1: NSTextField!

    //--------------------------------------------------------------
    // MARK: - viewDidLoad
    // MARK: -
    //--------------------------------------------------------------
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        //---------------------------------------------------------
        //setup text change delegates - see extension above
        connectTONSControlTextEditingDelegate()
        //---------------------------------------------------------
    }
}
```

Comment: I got error  override func controlTextDidChange(_ notification: Notification) Method does not override any method from its superclass